# Reviewing only changes I did not review before

Tags: github

I'm reviewing a huge GitHub pull request. I've reviewed the originally pushed code and made a lot of comments. Now I'm supposed to review the changes that were committed according to my comments but going through all the changed files is just inhumane. Is there a way to look through only the changes that I haven't reviewed yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the pull request and select the review tab (`Files changed`). On the left side of this tab there is a drop down "Changes from **all commits**". Change it to "Show changes since your last review".

[image: Screenshot]